# How do i ensure that an async objectify API call like "delete" completed successfully?

Tags: objectify

How do i ensure that an async objectify API call like "delete" completed successfully?

So, will "ofy().delete" throw some exception if it does not complete successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Call now().

```
ofy().delete().key(thing).now()
```

This will perform a synchronous delete operation.  Otherwise the async operation will be completed at the end of the request (make sure you install the `ObjectifyFilter`) and you will get an exception (say, a timeout) then.